# Remove Brews Unused for >= 3 Months

Tags: homebrew

Is there a way to remove brews that haven't been used for some time period - say 3 months or more?

I want an easy way to remove all the dependencies I installed for a 1 off thing then forgot to cleanup.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. macOS support questions should be posted to [apple.se] or [su] instead.

Comment: @JohnKugelman The solution to this problem is almost certainly programming-related

Comment: This will involve getting a list of all installed formulae and casks, and comparing their access times (`atime`). However, the complicated part is determining which formulae you installed vs which ones are dependencies of others.

Comment: What about periodically reviewing the output of `brew leaves` and then `brew uninstall a b c d`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do `brew cleanup -s`, which would cleanse the cached artifacts.

And you can also run `brew outdated`, which would give you some hints which can be removed.

Homebrew is not that smart to figure out your usage, because it does carry the database to do it. :)